# How to get all rows in certain month

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

I have a column named `DC34_DATE` of type `DATE` (defined this way: `DATE '2013-04-17'`). I need to select all rows for a specific month (for example April). I have used `WHERE MONTH(DC34_DATE)=04;` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should add your rdbms name also .answer may differ for MSSQL and MYSQL

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  And are you sure the data type is date and not varchar? Month(date) should work for several RDMBS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the extract from date function to get the date. Try this.

```
WHERE EXTRACT(month from DC34_DATE) = '4';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select yourColumns
from yourTable
where datepart(month,yourDateColumn)=4
```

TSQL solution..don't know which dialect you're using.